# Tweepy iterating over tweepy.Cursor(api.friends).items()

Tags: python-2.7, tweepy

I'm trying to get the friends of a user and append them to a list given a condition:

```
for friend in tweepy.Cursor(api.friends).items():
    if friend not in visited:
        screen_names.append(friend.screen_name)
        visited.append(friend.screen_name)
```

However I obtain an error:

`raise RateLimitError(error_msg, resp)
tweepy.error.RateLimitError: [{u'message': u'Rate limit exceeded', u'code': 88}]`

Could you give me any hint on solving this problem? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since tweepy 3.2+ you can instruct the tweepy library to wait for rate limits. This way you don't have to do that in your code.

To use this feature you would initialize your api handle as follows:

```
self.api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
```

The documentation for the new variables is below.

> - **wait_on_rate_limit** – Whether or not to automatically wait for rate    limits to replenish
> - **wait_on_rate_limit_notify** – Whether or not to    print a notification when Tweepy is waiting for rate limits to    replenish

Answer (score 4):

By default, `friends` method of `API` class, returns only list of 20 users per call, and by Twitter API you are limited to 15 calls only per window (15-minute). Thus you can only fetch 20 x 15 = 300 friends within 15-minutes.

`Cursor` in `tweepy` is another way of getting results without managing `cursor` value on each call to Twitter API.

You can increase the count of results fetched by per call, by including an extra parameter `count`.

```
tweepy.Cursor(api.friends, count = 200)
```

Maximum value of `count` can be 200. If you've friends more than 200 x 15 = 3000, than you need to use normal `api.friends` method, with maintaining `cursor` value and using `sleep` to distribute call timing. See [GET friends/list](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/friends/list) page for detailed info.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Twitter's API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting), you have reached your query limit. It looks like the rate limits are in effect for every 15 minutes of querying, so try again in 30 minutes or use a different IP Address to hit the API. If you scroll down Twitter's documentation, you will see your code 88.